# Not able to install libraries via 'pod install' command

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

While executing command pod install I am getting following error.

```
gsirn-021308:ApplePaySwag-Starter chandeln$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a target named `ApplePaySwag`, did find `    ` and `ApplePaySwagTests`.
```

Here is my directory structure:

```
gsirn-021308:ApplePaySwag-Starter chandeln$ ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x@ 16 chandeln  staff  544 Oct  3 16:56 ApplePaySwag
drwxr-xr-x@  5 chandeln  staff  170 Oct  3 16:56 ApplePaySwag.xcodeproj
drwxr-xr-x   4 chandeln  staff  136 Sep 15 15:38 ApplePaySwag.xcworkspace
drwxr-xr-x@  4 chandeln  staff  136 Sep 15 14:21 ApplePaySwagTests
-rw-r--r--@  1 chandeln  staff  455 Oct  3 17:44 Podfile
-rw-r--r--   1 chandeln  staff  209 Sep 19 11:12 Podfile.lock
drwxr-xr-x   8 chandeln  staff  272 Oct  3 17:44 Pods


gsirn-021308:ApplePaySwag-Starter chandeln$ pod --version
1.0.1
```

Podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ApplePaySwag' do

  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ApplePaySwag
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'SwiftyXMLParser', :git => 'https://github.com/yahoojapan/SwiftyXMLParser.git'

  target 'ApplePaySwagTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Not sure what am I missing here. Please guide.

Comment: What is the output of 'xcodebuild -list'?

Comment: A target here is not a file, it's a build target described _inside_ your xcodeproj. Open the xcworkspace, select your ApplePaySwag.xcodeproj and inside the bar that says "General", "Build settings" and such, all the way to the left, click on the blue xcodeproj icon and select rename the target that seems to be named "     ".

Comment: Can you post the code your Podfile?

Comment: @Jonas - That worked !! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added as answer so you can mark it as accepted and close the question :

> A target here is not a file, it's a build target described inside your xcodeproj. Open the xcworkspace, select your ApplePaySwag.xcodeproj and inside the bar that says "General", "Build settings" and such, all the way to the left, click on the blue xcodeproj icon and select rename the target that seems to be named " ".

Answer (score 0):

Your pods seem to be correct, but the cocoa pod that your trying to install seems to not be correct, best thing to do is double check to make sure you are typing in the exact name for the cocoa pod.